# How to change the size of an image or image view in the navigationBar (not the file-size)

Tags: ios, ios13, swift5

I'm trying to get an application working for my work. In this application we want to show a website via WKWebViewKit and in the navigationBar should be the logo of our company. There is also a refresh button which should reload the URL which I typed in into the code, not only the page which is opened at the moment.

I already tried finding a solution, but the Image is still in the complete size of the navigationBar. I also found no solution for the refresh button. Last time I used the history go back -1 because I only had one following page, but in this project there are hundreds of following pages the user might click on.

Here's the code for the ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

        // 2
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let navController = self.navigationController!

        navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        let image = UIImage (named: "logo-white")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

       let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image!.size.width / 2
       let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image!.size.height / 2

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
imageView.frame = ...
```

No. Give the image view height and width *constraints*, not a frame.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced it with this snippet of code I found on the web, now it's working:

```
        let logoContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 25))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 25))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo-white")
        imageView.image = image
        logoContainer.addSubview(imageView)
        navigationItem.titleView = logoContainer
```

But my second question was not answered about the refresh-button :-(

How to load a new website by clicking on the refresh-button:

```
// 2
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also find that no matter what you set, the width and height have no effect. It seems that I have not found `UIStackView` through the view hierarchy, but one thing is certain: the width and height constraints of `titleView`, `navigationItem` is already done, the width is about a certain distance from the left and right, and the height is equal.

Next you can do this, but it is generally recommended to use `autolayout`, I am using `SnapKit` here.

```swift
let titleView = UIView()
let image = UIImage (named: "logo-white")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

titleView.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.center.equalTo(titleView)
     make.width.height.equalTo(40)
}
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```